# Intermediate fields in extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I don't know how to prove this inequality from Hungerford's Algebra book:

> Let $L$ and $M$ be intermediate fields in the extension $K\subset F$.
>   Prove that  $$[LM:K]\le[L:K][M:K].$$ 
>   Here, $LM$ is the subfield generated by $L\cup M.$

Comment: This is proposition 21 in the chapter on Algebraic Extensions (13.2) in Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ and $M$ are algebraic extensions, $LM$ is generated as a $k$-vector space by products of generators of $L$ and of $M$.

**EDIT:** I've worked out the infinite case, if you want it. The main observation is that a transcendental extension of $K$ has degree at least the cardinality of $K$, since if $x$ is transcendental then the elements $1/(x-a)$ are linearly independent as $a$ runs over $K$. Thus such an extension $M$ has degree equal to its own cardinality: its cardinality is the cardinal product $|K|[M:K]=[M:K]$. Now $[LM:K]=|LM|=\max(|L|,|M|)=\max([L:K],[M:K])=[L:K][M:K]$.

Comment: This is only true when $L,M$ are algebraic over $K$. In general, we need quotients of such sums of products, and then we cannot write down a generating system as a vector space so easily, I think. But probably $F/K$ is assumed to be finite anyway and the OP didn't mention ...

Comment: @KevinCarlson that means the equality holds. Or am I wrong? I have checked it...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah, yes, I was assuming that without even thinking, thanks. I suppose it holds in general, but I don't see the proof in case $L$ and $M$ have cardinality greater than their degree over $K$. Al-Jabr: equality need not hold. Consider $L=M$.

Comment: I've now added a general proof.